# Webview dependency in Fluttter not working

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile-application

Can you help me figure out what's wrong with my codes. im receiving an error "The method 'WebView' isn't defined for the type '_UnamRadioHomePageState"  and i am getting errors on body: WebView() and javascriptMode, they're underlined.

```
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';
...

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('Unam Radio'),
  ),
  body: Column(
    children: [
      Expanded(
        child: WebView(
          initialUrl:
              'https://iono.fm/s/194', // Replace with your streaming URL
          javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
        ),
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
          child: _getPageForItem(_selectedItem),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
  drawer: UnamRadioDrawer(
    selectedItem: _selectedItem,
    onItemSelected: (item) {
      setState(() {
        _selectedItem = item;
      });
      Navigator.pop(context);
    },
   ),
   );
  }
 }
```

Comment: Have you checked your parentheses? I think you are missing a `)` in the end

Comment: @jraufeisen i think i missed that when i was editing the codes in the question panel

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have added the **webview_flutter** package to your **pubspec.yaml** file under dependencies.

If you haven't done that yet, add it like this:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  webview_flutter: ^4.2.4 # Use the latest version of webview_flutter
```